Read video data from Gstreamer and porcess
I send camera data to Serial COM port using this command
gst-launch-1.0 mfvideosrc device-index=0 ! video/x-raw, width=1280, height=720, framerate=10/1 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! filesink location=//.//COM20

It works well . Now i want to receive that data from my second device (COM19)
Smth like this
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=//.//COM19 ! autovideosink

I tried differnet ways , but none is worked.
What is the correct receive command?Thanks!

probably need to parse the data again on the receiving side with rawparse
something like
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=//.//COM19 ! rawparse ! videoconvert ! autovideosink

